# jquery insert class to all element before

Tags: jquery, html

I'm wondering how to solve a problem.
For example we're having:

```
<li>
  <a class="disabled">
</li>
<li>
  <a class="disabled">
</li>
<li>
  <a href ="http://..." class="active">
</li>
<li>
  <a class="disabled">
</li>
```

how to manage using jquery to add to `<a>` tag class NEWCLASS for all `<a>` before `<a>` with class active, so we're gonna obtain

```
<li>
  <a class="disabled NEWCLASS">
</li>
<li>
  <a class="disabled NEWCLASS">
</li>
<li>
  <a href ="http://..." class="active">
</li>
<li>
  <a class="disabled">
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need the selector of the parent `ul` or `ol`, but let's assume it's `LIST`.

```
// Get index of active link
before = $(".LIST li a").index($("a.active"))

// Add class to all links before active link
for (var i = 0; i < before; i += 1) {
    $(".LIST li a").eq(i).addClass("NEWCLASS");
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jnDs/1/).

Comment: Thank You for giving a help, i removed from script ".LIST" and it perfectly working ;)

Comment: @KordianWikliński  The `for` loop is also unnecessary. Might I ask why didn't go with my answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a.active').parent().prevAll().children('a').addClass('NEWCLASS')
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96FFS/)

Comment: Was just fiddling up the same thing! Nice, concise answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/):

```
$('li a.active').parent().siblings().prev().children('a').not('.active').addClass('NEWCLASS');
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mdajm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var activeAnchor = $('li a.active').parent().prevAll("li:has(a)").find('a.disabled').toggleClass('disabled active');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HC4EY/)

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
$( "a.active" ).each(function( index ) {
    $( this ).addClass( "NEWCLASS" );
});
```

Comment: -1. This will apply `.NEWCLASS` to the `li > a` elements appearing **after** `a.active` too.